# Showing that this functional is unbounded

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H=L^2(a,b)$, and let $t_0$ be a fixed point in $(a,b)$. Let $f$ be the functional $H$ defined by $f(x)=x(t_0)$.

I wish to show that this functional is unbounded. I tried proof by contradiction but failed to get a contradiction. Is it actually bounded? Intuitively, it makes more sense to be unbounded. Either way, I am having trouble constructing a proof. Any help would be appreciated!

---

Edit: It is Example 3.7.2. in the photo below

[image]

Comment: Does $x(t_0)$ have a precise meaning? An element of $L^2 (a, b)$ is only defined up to equivalence almost everywhere.

Comment: @KennyWong No, it does not have a precise meaning. This was an example from my textbook as a functional that is linear but not bounded. I was having a hard time seeing why it is not bounded and was attempting to prove it.

Comment: @Dragonite it is probably better to put a photo of the exercise. Although, they may be considering the prehilbert space $\mathscr{L}^2$ in lieu of the Hilbert space $\mathbf{L}^2.$

Comment: The question has no meaning because $f$ is  not  a well defined function.

Comment: Yes, my answer was wrong. I deleted it. The function is really not well defined.

Comment: @WillM.I have included a photo from the book as requested.

Comment: What is the definition of $L^2$ in this book? Because if it is a space of equivalence classes then there is no meaning to a value at a point.

Comment: @Dragonite What book is this. I advise you not to read this book.

Comment: If there is a mistake it doesn't mean the whole book is bad. Nobody is perfect.

Comment: Probably it was meant $C(a, b) $ with the $L^2 $ norm.

Comment: @Mark It is defined essentially the same as: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Space.html

Comment: Unbounded operators are often assumed to be defined only on a dense subset, and I suspect that this problem is tacitly assumes so. But even in such case, it would have been much better to explicate the true domain of $f$.

Comment: @Dragonite Well, if you don't take equivalence classes then it is not a normed space at all. The so called "norm" here is actually a seminorm, because not only the zero vector has norm which is equal to zero. Or maybe they mean that you have to choose one function from each equivalence class.

Comment: @Dragonite Well, I updated my answer for the case where it is $C(a,b)$ with the $L^2$ norm. In that case it works well. In $L^2$ it just isn't a functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was explained in the comments the functional is not well defined. But let's suppose the meaning was $C(a,b)$ with the norm of $L^2$. In that case the functional is well defined and really not bounded. Take a big enough $M>0$ such that $(t_0-\frac{1}{2M},t_0+\frac{1}{2M})\subseteq (a,b)$. Then define $x$ like this: $x$ is increasing linearly from $0$ to $M$ in $[t_0-\frac{1}{2M},t_0]$, then decreasing linearly from $M$ to $0$ in $[t_0,t_0+\frac{1}{2M}]$ and everywhere else it is zero. Then let $y=\sqrt{x}$, this is also a continuous function. Then obviously $|f(y)|=\sqrt{M}$ and $||y||_2=(\int_a^b |y|^2dt)^{\frac{1}{2}}=(\int_a^b xdt)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1$, this is clear from imagining the area below the graph in a geometric way. So $\sup_{y\ne 0}\frac{|f(y)|}{||y||_2}\geq \sqrt{M}$. This is true for any big enough $M$, so the supremum is not finite and the functional is not bounded.